# Objective c - iCarousel Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, icarousel

I am implementing iCarousel (using Rotary) to display bunch of images, but i need it to be implemented with little bit of tilt in the two back images like in the image below.

[image]

Is this possible? If possible how can i change iCarousel library to implement this?

I could achive the following effect which is close to what i wanted using Wheel type, but now the problem is i need to send this 2nd image behind the front view.

[image]

I changed the parameters as following to get this effect inside - (CATransform3D)transformForItemView:(UIView *)view withOffset:(CGFloat)offset method

CGFloat spacing = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionSpacing withDefault:0.65f];
CGFloat arc = [self valueForOption:iCarouselOptionArc withDefault:M_PI / 3.0f];

Comment: Anything is possible if you code it. Have you looked at the transforms available to you and tried creating a custom transform to rotate the images a little bit?

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Did you play around with this delegate?

```
carousel:itemTransformForOffset:baseTransform:
```